# Designing a database for Questions, Options and Answers

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

A practice in trying to adhere to relational database techniques.
Can anyone give me a little bump as to what I'm doing wrong/how this should be?

In Short All Questions have 5 Possible Answers. That's the whole database act.

My idea/what I've thought to do so far was create three tables:

`questions`

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `question` mediumtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`options`

```
CREATE TABLE `options` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 INDEX choice_index (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
        REFERENCES questions(question_id),
 `answer_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `answer_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `answer_3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `answer_4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `answer_5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`choices_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here's where I'm coming to a dead-end.

`answers`

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ??`answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL
 //Foreign Key?
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

A foreign key has to be an integer value<sup>1</sup> -- but my answer choices are all `varchar(255)`.

What is the proper way to link these three tables up?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is an assumption, since most if not all relational schemas I've seen are "binded" by integer values, so that is where this assumption is coming from.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between `questions` and `options` is one-to-one, so if you wanted to simplify your table structure, then these two tables could be merged into one.

Are you 100% certain that every question will have only 5 (or less) options? For flexibility reasons, it might make sense to have only one answer option per record. In that case, the `options` table must remain separate from the `questions` table, and it becomes a one-to-many relationship.

Which is the right answer option? You should probably indicate that somehow.

In the `answers` table, the `answer_id`is obviously the primary key. The `question_id` is a foreign key. And you seem to have forgotten a foreign key to `options`, as well as a foreign key to a `users` table to indicate who gave this answer.

A minor issue: In the `questions` table, the `question` column is a `MEDIUMTEXT`. This is up to 16 million bytes. Do you really need that many? A `TEXT` column can store up to 64K bytes, maybe that would be enough?

Also, you would want to use `int unsigned` for your `auto_increment` columns. The reason for this is that auto incrementing ints start at 1, so by allowing signed `int`s you're effectively wasting a bit and limiting the range of values you can use.

There may be other opportunities for improvements, these are just a few I noticed.

Comment: This helped, thank you! Broke it down and everything you said makes sense (or will once I process it some more-- first time hearing about unsigned keys, have to look into that more). Still need to revise but going to post the structure below.. broke it down to two tables per your advice, and it looks pretty clean so far.  Still, a work in progress.

Comment: Aside from there being more key's than columns in the answers table haha. Just kind of noticed that, and not entirely sure. Gonna have to delve deeper into each one to see of its efficacy

Comment: @BrianBruman I've updated the answer to explain better about `int unsigned`.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Surprised I haven't heard about this before, but I guess that's because it's usually by default signed I'm guessing.  But yes negative numbers are not necessary for `auto_increment`s :). Will make the fix thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting progress with this, but was able to revamp it down to two tables. Haven't looked too deeply in column structure yet-- working on getting the relationship schema down first. Any advice or thoughts on this would be helpful and appreciated. Just finished this so there might be some gaps.

Here we go.

## Table #1: Questions

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `answer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
 KEY `questions_index` (`answer_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `questions_index` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `answers` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

## Table #2: Answers

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `question_index` (`question_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `answers_index` (`answer`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `answer_index` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `questions` (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And a PHPMyAdmin Visual (with mouse over)

> questions:

[image]

> answers:

[image]

Happy so far, but I'm sure there is more to do. Especially if I wish to expand from this basic template. Any thoughts appreciated as I said it is still a work in progress, but the simplicity behind it seems nice (but what do I know :)?)

And in fact have no idea what `USING BTREE` is actually.. not even a clue how it got in my structure or what its use is. Going to look into this soon.

Comment: Looks better, but how are you going to record what users have answered? Also, I don't think the index on the `answer` column is useful.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. Haven't yet come up with anything yet. And thank you I will check that.